# How can I customize Authentication in Django rest framework because data source for django is External API not any traditional database

Tags: python-3.x, django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework

I am trying to authenticate user in django but user details are in elasticsearch.

In this project we are not using any traditional database.

Our requirement is that if user sends a request to DRF API for login with username and password we have to fetch the data from elasticsearch and verify the username and password and if it is correct user is authenticated.
After that If I try to access any Protected API I have to send these credentials in every request I am not able to get how can I implement session in that case so that after login a session will be created and used to authenticate if user is trying to access protected APIs.

## I have created custom authentication method:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import BaseAuthentication
from rest_framework.exceptions import AuthenticationFailed
from myapp.elastic_helper import ElasticsearchClient

class ElasticsearchAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        username = request.data.get('username')
        password = request.data.get('password')

        if not username or not password:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Login is required')

        response = ElasticsearchClient().get_user_from_elasticsearch(username=username)

        if response['hits']['total']['value'] != 1:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Invalid username or password')

        user_data = response['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']

        if user_data.get('password') != password:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Invalid password')
            
        user = CustomUser(username, user_data)
        request.session['username'] = username
        return user, user_data

class CustomUser:
    def __init__(self, username, user_data):
        self.username = username
        self.user_data = user_data

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True
```

## This is my views

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.exceptions import AuthenticationFailed
from myapp.authentication import ElasticsearchAuthentication
from myapp.elastic_helper import ElasticsearchClient

class ElasticsearchLoginView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def post(self, request):
        authentication = ElasticsearchAuthentication()
        # Authenticate the user using the custom Elasticsearch authentication class
        try:
            user, user_data = authentication.authenticate(request)
        except AuthenticationFailed as e:
            return Response({'error': str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        
        
        # Return user data upon successful authentication
        return Response({"Message": "Authentication is successfull", "result": user_data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    
class ArticleView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        article_data = ElasticsearchClient().get_articles()

        if not article_data:
            return Response({"Message": "No article Found"}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        
        result = []
        for i in article_data:
            result.append(i['_source'])

        return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    
class LogoutAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        return Response({'message': 'Logout successful'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```